# Texture only applying to part of face

Tags: texturing, uv, image, faces

I'm new at blender so might be something stupid but couldn't find the answer anywhere.

I'm trying to apply a texture to only a face of an object but only part of it is applied. I'm using cycles and a simple node setup consisting of image texture passing into the diffuse. I've selected the face and UV unwrapped it. I've tried moving the face around in the UV editor and it doesn't make any difference. I've also tried re-calculating the normals but it didn't help either.

Thanks to anyone who's willing to help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you provided you image with texture coordinates input in the material?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. I hadn't so I tried adding one but the issue still persists.

Comment: And which one did you use exactly, UV Map? Because if you are unwrapping your mesh you need to specifically use *UV Map* type coordinates. Also if you have more than one UV map on your mesh you need a *UV Map* node so you can specify which one to use.

Comment: I used UV map and I only have one UV map on my mesh.

Comment: Well then I'm out of ideas you will have to provide way more details for a proper answer, namely mesh topology, uv map, material settings, node setup, and possibly a upload demo file we can look at. Please edit your question and provide more details and screenshots.

Comment: I added some information but can't add much more as I don't have high enough reputation. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Could you please provide a as **simplified file** as [possible reproducing the problem](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3077" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3077/)

I've manage to reproduce the error in a way although I have UV mapped multiple times to get it so might be a different error.

Comment: Your model is full of duplicate geometry and overlapping vertex with residual zero sided faces. Those are causing the issues. Removing them will cause your model to change so you will likely have to add a lot more control loops